# parse in a script parameters sent to a mount point

Tags: icecast

I have defined a mount point in my Icecast server, for example data.ogg. I would like to send some parameters to the mount point I have defined,
for example /data.ogg?param1=x1&param2=x2&param3=x3. I have tried to parse these parameters in a new script and I could only parse the mount point /data.ogg. I have the following question:

**How to parse the other parameters (param1,param2 and param3) in a new script?**

I have just checked the manual and the information:
https://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.0/auth.html

Comment: How are you running that script? Please include relevant configuration details.

Comment: Hello , I have a .sh script which is run in the icecast when a new request is parsed.It is located in the <on-connect>/bin/testIcecast.sh<on-connect> in the icecast.xml file The content of the file is the following :                          
    #!/bin/sh                                                                                                   
    echo $1 >/tmp/test.txt;
The question that I have is the following : If I make the follwoing request : http://xxxxxxx:8000/data.ogg?param1=test1&param2=test2
How to parse param1 and param2 parameter from the Script?
Regards
Gorka